# Drupal Themes for Data Analytics Website

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-themes

Please suggest some free themes for building a website for Data Analytics domain.

Found some, but that does not appeal me much.

thanks

Comment: You don't say why the themes you looked at don't appeal to you, and saying "a website for Data Analytics domain" doesn't give us any clues. Could you ask a question that is possible for us to answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [theme](https://drupal.org/project/simplecorp) and you can plug some Analytic modules in it. If you wish I can name them.

Comment: This looks good. Goona try it for my website. In the meanwhile can you please suggest some more good themes available for free.